# How can I subscribe to a page's updates on Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to the "Real Time Updates" heading on the page reference in the Facebook graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/), I should call https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs with a POST request to be able to subscribe to a page's events. However, when I do that in the Graph API Explorer (and my app as well), I get an error like this:

One and only one of params "tab" or "app_id" must be provided.

This doesn't make sense because Facebook would have no way of knowing which application is trying to subscribe to this page's events.

I should also note that I'm making this request after first setting the access token to the page's access token, and getting the manage_pages permission from the user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I needed to explicitly send the app_id argument:

```
<?php
// $facebook is the Facebook object (imagine that I've already initialized it)
$facebook->api($pageId . '/tabs', array(
    'app_id' => $facebook->getAppId(),
));
?>
```